# Parallelization of multiple numpy.linalg.multi_dot calls

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, pool

I'm trying to parallelize this function:

```
def update_G_left(self):
    num = np.linalg.multi_dot([self.association_matrix,
                               self.G_right, self.S.transpose()])
    den = np.linalg.multi_dot([self.G_left, self.S, self.G_right.transpose(),
                               self.G_right, self.S.transpose()])

    for am in self.dep_own_left_other_left:
        num += np.linalg.multi_dot([am.association_matrix,
                                    am.G_right, am.S.transpose()])
        den += np.linalg.multi_dot([self.G_left, am.S, am.G_right.transpose(),
                                    am.G_right, am.S.transpose()])
    for am in self.dep_own_left_other_right:
        num += np.linalg.multi_dot([am.association_matrix.transpose(),
                                    am.G_left, am.S])
        den += np.linalg.multi_dot([self.G_left, am.S.transpose(), 
                                    am.G_left.transpose(), am.G_left, am.S])
    div = np.divide(num, den + sys.float_info.min)
    return np.multiply(self.G_left, div)
```

The function is working well, but when I use pools:

```
def update_G_left(self):
    num = np.linalg.multi_dot([self.association_matrix, self.G_right, self.S.transpose()])
    den = np.linalg.multi_dot([self.G_left, self.S, self.G_right.transpose(), self.G_right, self.S.transpose()])
    with multiprocessing.Pool(6) as pool:
        for x in pool.map(np.linalg.multi_dot,
                          [[am.association_matrix, am.G_right, am.S.transpose()]
                           for am in self.dep_own_right_other_left]):
            num += x
        for x in pool.map(np.linalg.multi_dot,
                          [[self.G_left, am.S,
                            am.G_right.transpose(), am.G_right, am.S.transpose()]
                           for am in self.dep_own_right_other_left]):
            den += x
        for x in pool.map(np.linalg.multi_dot,
                          [[am.association_matrix.transpose(), am.G_left, am.S]
                           for am in self.dep_own_right_other_right]):
            num += x
        for x in pool.map(np.linalg.multi_dot,
                          [[self.G_left, am.S.transpose(),
                            am.G_left.transpose(), am.G_left, am.S]
                           for am in self.dep_own_right_other_right]):
            den += x
    div = np.divide(num, den + sys.float_info.min)  
    return np.multiply(self.G_left, div)
```

Now it is no more working.

I get the error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,6) (7,6) (10,6)` at the second `num += x` .
I'm wondering why because i don't see any differences in the code.
There are other patterns to parallelize my function?

Comment: in the serial version you have `dep_own_left_other_right` while in the parallel version you have `dep_own_right_other_right` ... you need to look for a better naming convention, and your naming convention should be replaced by a list or dictionary to improve visibility.

Comment: Did you check `np.linalg.multi_dot` is not already running in parallel? AFAIK `np.linalg.dot` call a BLAS primitive which is parallel for relatively large arrays (the default BLAS library are already parallel). Running a parallel code in parallel is not efficient due to the over-subscription of the kernel scheduler. Additionally, multiprocessing tends not to be an efficient way to parallelize such a thing due to data transfer between processes (Python is actually a mess for that).

Comment: What's the sgape of your arays? All the same, or similar?  `multi_dot` helps most when shapes differ signjcantly, and thus a cerrain order is most efficient. For equal shaoed arrays it may actually be slower than the obvious `A@B@C...`